# Locally modified /boot/grub/menu.lst on update ubuntu 16.04 with AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm running **ubuntu 16.04** on an **Amazon AWS EC2** and have just run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to update the suggested packages in the **console**.

During which I have been prompted with `A new version of /boot/grub/menu.lst is available, but the version installed currently has been locally modified.` in the **package configuration** of `menu.lst`

We haven't made any changes so I am to assume that this is a setting by Amazon AWS EC2.

**How should I proceed?**

```
Line by line differences between versions

--- /run/grub/menu.lst root.root 0644 2018-01-25 22:33:02
+++ /tmp/fileeCfBYY root.root 0600 2018-01-25 22:33:02
@@ -3,11 +3,9 @@
   title Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, kernel 4.4.0-97-generic 
   root (hd0)
   kernel /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-97-generic root=LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs ro console=hvc0
-initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-97-generic 

   title Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, kernel 4.4.0-97-generic (recovery mode)
   root (hd0)
   kernel /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-97-generic root=LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs ro single 
-initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-97-generic 

### END DEBIAN AUTOMAGIC KERNELS LIST
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you haven't installed anything custom just select the "package maintainer's version".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

File permissions have changed

```
old : root.root 0644
new : root.root 0600
```

as suggested I would select "package maintainer's version"

Comment: Thank you. Choosing this hasn't affected anything that I can see, everything operating as it should and the world is still here.